# Arrangements and Selections with Repetitions: positive integer solutions of $x+y+z = 17$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many positive integer solutions are there to the equation $x+y+z = 17$?

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Check out the classic [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem.

There are two "versions": one for the number of non-negative integer solutions, the other for the number of positive integer solutions.

You want the latter:

> For any pair of positive integers $n$ and $k,$ the number of distinct $n$-tuples of positive integers whose sum is $k$ is given by the binomial coefficient  $$\binom {k-1}{n-1}.$$

For your equation, $n = 3, \;k=17$.

Comment: Is the answer 560?

Comment: Did you calculate $\dbinom{k - 1}{n-1} = \dbinom{17-1}{3-1}= \dbinom {16}{2} = \dfrac{16!}{2!\,14!} = 120$

Comment: No, I forgot to insert 2 instead of 3 and subtract 16 by 2 instead of 3. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're very welcome. Be sure to read the entry on the "stars and bars" problem. It really does a nice job of explaining *why* each formula (Theorem) works for the two versions, respectively. That will help you remember the two.

Comment: My book doesn't go into a lot of detail. The theorem it shows is for repetition . $C(s+t-1,s)$.

Comment: I'm referring to link in my post to "the stars and bars" entry in Wikipedia.